# Htaccess url rewrite not working correctly

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

I have an issue with url rewriting, here's what I have so far:

```
        Options +FollowSymlinks
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteRule \.(gif|png|jpg|css|js)$|^index\.php$ - [L]
        RewriteRule ^users/(.+)$ /profile.php?userid=$1 [NC]
        RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)$ /main.php?region=$1&place=$2 [NC]
```

Basically, if the url is mysite.com/users/username I want it to use profile.php, then for anything else, to go to main.php.

However, with that code it doesn't happen as expected, it always uses main.php. Is there anyway you can use if and elses in htaccess, or something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing `L` flag from 2nd and 3rd rules. Have your code like this:

```
RewriteRule \.(gif|png|jpg|css|js)$|^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^users/(.+)$ /profile.php?userid=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)$ /main.php?region=$1&place=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: L - Last Rule and QSA - Query String Append. Please refer http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: That site doesn't load for me :\

Comment: Actually that URL is up now. You can also check: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/a-deeper-look-at-mod_rewrite-for-apache/